# File Download with GUID name in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I Want to download the files present in the Folder i.e App_Data.This file I have saved with GUID but not able to download.
My code is as follows:

```
public FilePathResult DownLoadDispatch(long CIDInvID)
{
    var Attr = db.ConsolidatedInvoiceDispatchDocuments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConsolidatedInvoiceDispatchID == CIDInvID);
    string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/files/Dispatch/" + Attr.StoredName.ToString();
    string fileName = Attr.FileName;
    return File(path + fileName, "text/plain", "test.txt");
}
```

Comment: What is `Attr.StoredName` and how does it differ from `Attr.FileName`? Without knowing what those values contain it kind of looks like you're tacking on the filename twice. Have you tried using the debugger to check the values of `path` and `fileName` to ensure they contain the correct values?

Comment: fileName>>Name of the file into the Databse and the path>>Path of the file in the database that I am retrieving using Attr Variable

Comment: Is `path + fileName` what you expect it to be? Is there a path separator missing? I would always suggest `Path.Combine()` over concatenating the paths yourself.

Comment: Do have the code for this?I am missing something offcourse

Comment: `Path.Combine(path, fileName);`. You could also use it to combine your `MapPath()` result with the hard-coded portion and the stored name.